# Tracking previous page in JSF

Tags: jsf, navigation

I want to find out the previous page from where the current page is called. Based on the previous page I want to enable or disable a particular component. Can anybody help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the concrete functional requirement which isn't entirely clear from your question. You could pass an unique request parameter. E.g. when it concerns a GET link:

```html
<h:link value="Next" outcome="next">
    <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</h:link>
```

or a POST link:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Next" action="next">
        <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

with in `next.xhtml`

```html
<h:someComponent rendered="#{param.foo == 'bar'}">
    ...
</h:someComponent>
```

or if you don't care about the param's value:

```html
<h:someComponent rendered="#{not empty param.foo}">
    ...
</h:someComponent>
```

---

An alternative which can be much better if you don't want to allow the enduser being able to manipulate the request is to set a bean property during a POST action and then return to the next view:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Next" action="#{bean.next}" />
</h:form>
```

with e.g.

```
public String next() {
    foo = "bar";
    return "next";
}
```

and in `next.xhtml`

```html
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.foo == 'bar'}">
    ...
</h:someComponent>
```

Comment: I am using <f:param> with <hx:commandExButton>(which transaltes to <input type="submit">) which is an IBM implementation of JSF and it is not working. Can I pass it as an input hidden type?

Comment: You're still on old JSF 1.x? Use a command link instead. `<f:param>` in command buttons works in JSF 2.x only. If you're using JSF 1.2 (and thus not JSF 1.1!) then you could also opt to use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instead. This allows you to set a bean property directly instead of passing it as a manipulatable request parameter.